# Looping isometric animation

Tags: animation

I’m looking at making a music video with blender. I’m fine with modelling but I’ve never really done much in the way of animation,

I want the video to consist of a camera following a road From an  isometric perspective.

How should I approach this?

i don’t want to model 3 minutes worth of road with all the buildings so I’ll need some sort of looping.

Any tutorials I should look at? Any keywords?

Thanks from one of those annoying newbs

Comment: Hello and welcome. Asking for tutorials and links to resources is considered off topic here. Could you please rephrase your question to focus specifically on which part you are having difficulties.

Comment: As long as all your animation is linear (consistent and does not speed up/down) it should just be a matter of matching frame n to frame 1 and allowing it to repeat. Try with a really simple layout of road/plane and buildings/Cubes.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a path (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>  *> Curve > Path*) that you want the camera to follow. After that, move the camera to the starting position of the path.

Then set the path as a parent of the camera (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>  on a PC) and select *Follow Path*.

In the path settings, you can now set the duration of the animation. Using a constraint you can even make the camera track another object or always look forward or whatever.